# Verify / Check permissions of all running Windows services

Tags: windows, icacls

I am trying to verify permissions of all services running on windows. Though verifying permissions individually is quite painful.

Is there any way of piping the result from windows command `net start` to `icacls`, to identify permissions for all services?

Comment: how do you use icacls with services?

Answer (score 1):

`for %s in (*.exe) do icacls %s` //Ensure this command is executed after navigating into C://Windows/System32 directory